# Записать stdout одной программы в stdin другой

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Есть такая задача: проверить скорость работы программы путём скармливания ей большого количества случайно генерируемых данных данных.

Проверяемая программа принимает значения через cin, выводит через cout.
Возможно ли читать и писать в эти потоки из другой программы и возможно ли реализовать это это средствами C++14? Если да, то как?

Если не возможно, то как это можно реализовать под виндой?

Comment: А что, перенаправление уже отменили? `|`?

Comment: Проще использовать перенаправление ввода-вывода на уровне самой OS: src.exe | dest.exe

Comment: В \*nix-ах это реализуется теми же средствами C++-14, что и любого, совместимого с Си языка. Посмотрите на системные вызовы `pipe`, `fork`, `dup`